# How to pass data into the DOM using querySelector

Tags: javascript, dom, innerhtml, selectors-api, innertext

I'm using querySelectorAll to access id & classes within my index.html file. The problem that I am having is that I'm trying to pass data into my p.source class which has two child spans, and when I use innerText or innerHTML the data isn't being passed into the DOM despite my console log showing the correct data that is meant to be passed into the DOM. Could you help me understand what it is that happening and how I can pass the data into that source class. I'm new to using querySelector and the MDN documentation isn't as quiet in depth as I'd like. Below is my code.

So far by using the console I've tried to access the properties of the childeNodes and they work correctly its just getting that data to be reflected within the DOM

```js
function myQuotes() {
  var quotes = [{
      quote: "Seven billion souls that move around the sun.",
      source: "Childish Gambino",
      citation: "Feels like summer"
    },
    {
      quote: "Don't wait for your world to begin crumbling to make a change.",
      source: "Josh",
      citation: "Past midnight thoughts"
    },
    {
      quote: "The only time we will ever have is right now, no other time exist.",
      source: "Josh",
      citation: "Past midnight thoughts",
      year: 2018
    },
    {
      quote: "Every great developer you know got there by solving problems they were unqualified to solve until they actually did it.",
      source: "Patrick McKenzie",
      citation: "Twitter"

    }
  ];

  console.log('quotes', quotes);

  return quotes;
}

var myQuotesLength = myQuotes().length;
var quotes = myQuotes();

function getRandomQuote(maxNum) {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum);
  var randomQuote = quotes[randomNum];
  // console.log('random quote', randomQuote );
  return randomQuote;
}



function printQuote() {
  //data call to grab quotes from array of objects
  var message = getRandomQuote(myQuotesLength);
  console.log('message', message);

  //using querySelectors to dynamically pass the data from 'message' into the DOM. Each field works except for sourceField.
  var quoteField = document.querySelectorAll('.quote')[0].innerText = message.quote;
  var source_Parent = document.querySelectorAll('.source');
  console.log('parent', source_Parent);
  var sourceField = source_Parent[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML = message.source;
  console.log('source', sourceField);
  var citationField = source_Parent[0].childNodes[1].innerText = message.citation;
  var yearField = source_Parent[0].childNodes[2].innerText = message.year;
  if (yearField === undefined) {
    yearField = document.getElementsByClassName('year')[0].innerHTML = ' ';
  }
}

document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #36b55c;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

#quote-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  line-height: .5;
}

.quote {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.quote:before,
.quote:after {
  font-size: 6rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.quote:before {
  content: "“";
  top: .25em;
  left: -.5em;
}

.quote:after {
  content: "”";
  bottom: -.1em;
  margin-left: .1em;
  position: absolute;
}

.source {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  ;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 4em;
}

.source:before {
  content: "—";
}

.citation {
  font-style: italic;
}

.citation:before {
  content: ", ";
  font-style: normal;
}

.year:before {
  content: ", ";
  font-style: normal;
}

#loadQuote {
  position: fixed;
  width: 12em;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6em;
  bottom: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #36b55c;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

#loadQuote:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

#loadQuote:focus {
  outline: none;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .quote {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  .quote:before,
  .quote:after {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  .source {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="container">
  <div id="quote-box">
    <p class="quote">Every great developer you know got there by solving problems they were unqualified to solve until they actually did it.</p>
    <p class="source">Patrick McKenzie<span class="citation">Twitter</span><span class="year">2016</span></p>
  </div>
  <button id="loadQuote">Show another quote</button>
</div>
```

The end result is:

-I'd like to pass the message.quote data into the innerHTML of quote-box id (this works)

-I'd like to pass the message.source data into the innerText of source class (this doesn't work)

-I'd like to pass the message.citation data into the innerText of citation class (this works)

-I'd like to pass the message.year data into the innerText of year class (this works)

Comment: This: _**message.quote; //Displays data in the DOM correctly**_ is not possible given the code displayed here. If there is other code that makes this work, PLEASE include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @RandyCasburn please see link to code pen to see complete code set. I had to reformat it to get to the meat of my question which is how to pass data into the p tag. Everything works correctly.

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is considered bad practice to force someone off-site to get the basic idea of your question. Please always include the relevant code in your question. That CodePen will go away and won't be available for future answer seekers to view. I'm certain you can imagine how confusing your question will appear as it stands now because as written in the question, there is no possible way `message.quote` would work.

Comment: Got it, thanks @RandyCasburn. Will correct code formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing the name as a childNode, but its not a childNode of the `.source div`, its an `innerText`. If you put the name into a `<span>` too, it will became a childNode too and will work like a charm.

> Here is your 'fixed' codepen, where i've just added a `<span>` around the name:
>   https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pGrBEo?editors=1010#0

Or take a look at this working example:

```js
function myQuotes() {
  var quotes = [{
      quote: "Seven billion souls that move around the sun.",
      source: "Childish Gambino",
      citation: "Feels like summer"
    },
    {
      quote: "Don't wait for your world to begin crumbling to make a change.",
      source: "Josh",
      citation: "Past midnight thoughts"
    },
    {
      quote: "The only time we will ever have is right now, no other time exist.",
      source: "Josh",
      citation: "Past midnight thoughts",
      year: 2018
    },
    {
      quote: "Every great developer you know got there by solving problems they were unqualified to solve until they actually did it.",
      source: "Patrick McKenzie",
      citation: "Twitter"

    }
  ];
  return quotes;
}

var myQuotesLength = myQuotes().length;
var quotes = myQuotes();

function getRandomQuote(maxNum) {
  var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum);
  var randomQuote = quotes[randomNum];
  return randomQuote;
}



function printQuote() {
  var message = getRandomQuote(myQuotesLength);

  var quoteField = document.querySelectorAll('.quote')[0].innerText = message.quote;
  var source_Parent = document.querySelectorAll('.source');
  var sourceField = source_Parent[0].childNodes[0].innerHTML = message.source;
  var citationField = source_Parent[0].childNodes[1].innerText = message.citation;
  var yearField = source_Parent[0].childNodes[2].innerText = message.year;
  if (yearField === undefined) {
    yearField = document.getElementsByClassName('year')[0].innerHTML = ' ';
  }
}

document.getElementById('loadQuote').addEventListener("click", printQuote, false);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #36b55c;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
}

#quote-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20%;
  left: 10%;
  right: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  line-height: .5;
}

.quote {
  font-size: 4rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 1.1;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
}

.quote:before,
.quote:after {
  font-size: 6rem;
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  position: absolute;
}

.quote:before {
  content: "“";
  top: .25em;
  left: -.5em;
}

.quote:after {
  content: "”";
  bottom: -.1em;
  margin-left: .1em;
  position: absolute;
}

.source {
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  ;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-align: right;
  margin-right: 4em;
}

.source:before {
  content: "—";
}

.citation {
  font-style: italic;
}

.citation:before {
  content: ", ";
  font-style: normal;
}

.year:before {
  content: ", ";
  font-style: normal;
}

#loadQuote {
  position: fixed;
  width: 12em;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6em;
  bottom: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #36b55c;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: .5s;
}

#loadQuote:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

#loadQuote:focus {
  outline: none;
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .quote {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
  .quote:before,
  .quote:after {
    font-size: 3rem;
  }
  .source {
    font-size: 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

<div class="container">
  <div id="quote-box">
    <p class="quote">Every great developer you know got there by solving problems they were unqualified to solve until they actually did it.</p>
    <p class="source"><span>Patrick McKenzie</span><span class="citation">Twitter</span><span class="year">2016</span></p>
  </div>
  <button id="loadQuote">Show another quote</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help with the edit and also the tip about <span>. Wouldn't have reached that conclusion.  So question, because its innerText would there be anyway to write directly to it? Only asking to close the loop in case I run into a use case where I'm not able to modify the html.

Comment: if you want to write directly into it, you could use `source_Parent[0].innerHTML = message.source + '<span class="citation"></span><span class="year"></span>;`. Note that you have to add the two `<span>`s for citation and year too, because in this case you are overwriting the innerHTML of the whole `<p>` and the `<span>`s would get lost.

Comment: ahhh okay mkaes a lot more sense now.  That was the problem I kept having when I was trying to `getELementsByClassName` I kept getting `innerHTML = undefined` for both `span`s only when I set the `innerHTML` for the `<p>` source class. Thanks for the insight man! This problem has plagued me for 48 hours.

Comment: you're welcome. please mark as the right answer if i solved your issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are using `childNodes` that also includes the text.

Here is a note from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)

`childNodes` includes all child nodes, including non-element nodes like text and comment nodes. To get a collection of only elements, use `ParentNode.children` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `createTextNode` and `insertBefore` methods, like:

```
const source = message.source;
const sourceNode = document.createTextNode(source);

const sourceEl = document.querySelectorAll(".source")[0];
const citationEl = document.querySelectorAll(".citation")[0];

sourceEl.insertBefore(sourceNode, citationEl);
```